# HTML local anchor doesn't work, web page is not reloaded

Tags: html, anchor

Greeting,

I am trying to use local anchor in a web page, but it doesn't work. The local anchor's URL like this:

https://hostname:port/info?newElement=true#a

If I use this URL to load the web page directly, I can see the web page is located in the correct position where the local anchor is. But if I click the hyper link in the web page, nothing happens, though I can see the URL is correct in the footer when I hover mouse on the hyper link.

The web page is not reloaded and the URL in the browser's address box is not changed to the URL with "#a" at end. Is it due to the web page is an active web page?

Below is the code sample:

"form.jsp":

```
<div>
    <div>
        <jsp:include page="form-nav.jsp" />
        <div>
            <jsp:include page="form-location.jsp" />
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"form-nav.jsp":

```
<div>
    <ul class="tab">
        <li>
            <a href="#location"> Name </a>
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
<div>
```

"form-location.jsp":

```
<div id="location" class="page">
...
</div>
```

Thanks, 
Zhe

Comment: can you please provide the code sample where you use anchor tag

Comment: your question should be more specific, try to post your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Hi, I have added some sample codes. The whole codes are huge, but the simple sample codes here are the main framework. Could you see is it specific enough?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/yo489xvp/)**</kbd>

Here is an example of how to use the anchor tag.

Anchor syntax:

```
<a href="#someid">Link text</a>
```

Referenced Element:

```
<div id="someid">You content goes in here</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, I try to use the same logic in the codes. But the problem is there is no response if I click the anchor's hyper link. Seems the page is not reloaded.

Comment: There should be no reloading on a redirect. just like in my **demo** link

Answer (score 0):

everyone,

by further codes reading, I found the problem now. There is a override of the hyper link's click behavior in a js file:

```
$("body..... ul.tab li a").on('click', function() {
    ...
    return false;
})
```

By deleting this override logic, the local anchor works well now. Thanks a lot for your comments!